# Why can't I curl to 127.0.0.1 localhost, but I can to the instance.localhost?

Tags: node.js, curl, browser, localhost, ip

When I connect to my server on localhost via web browser, it works, but when I curl to localhost, it does not work. I have to nslookup instance.localhost to find where my server is.

Why is instance.localhost not 127.0.0.1? How do I prevent my server from changing from 127.0.0.1?

Comment: Have you checked what's inside your `hosts` file? `nano /etc/hosts`

Comment: yes localhost  in etc/hosts/ is 127.0.0.1 but I am wondering why my server is not on 127.0.0.1, why is it being changed

Comment: Is your server using any port? If any, try adding that port to e.g. 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: my website is using port 5000, i can curl to my website using a different address I found on nslookup instance.localhost. So when I do nslookup instance.localhost, I get a different address that is not 127.0.0.1, I get something like 173.25.127.1, when i curl to 173.25.127.1:5000, it works. I am trying to figure out why my server is going from 127.0.0.1:5000 to 173.25.127.1:5000, i think its being forwarded to another port?

Comment: Yeah, prob a docker or a nginx instance. You can try using something like (in Mac): `sudo lsof -i tcp:5000` to see what's using that port and then kill that process